# No new line for theorem in enumerate

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate, theorems

I'm writing a solution to my assignment. When I put my theorem `\begin{thm}\end{thm}` after `\item`, there will be a new line after item number in enumeration. How to put the theorem right after the item number?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[a)]
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}
\item[b)]
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Don't doing this. It make will confuse readers. I expect that in list  you give some explanation which follows by theorems ... or don't use theorems.

Comment: @Zarko Its because in our assignment we have a list of questions. And in each question(item) I want to add a theorem to state what I'm proving.

Comment: Do these theorems need numbers, will \textbf{Theorem} do?

Comment: @JohnKormylo oh yes, that would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, there's no real need to use [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm). As such, dropping it in lieu of the default `\newtheorem` definition provides the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
  \item
    \begin{thm}
    This is a theorem.
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{thm}
  \item
    \begin{thm}
    This is another theorem.
    \end{thm}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) makes enumeration configuration easier.